# Which are the main steps to configure ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been working with ssh to connect my localhost to my VPS without trouble. But now, I want to do the same conversely (connect my VPS to my localhost). Why? Because I want to create a crontab job to send my backups to my localhost from VPS.

I've been searching for an answer, but I'm a bit confused about the difference between configuring in server or in localhost. Also, I guess it could produce a security hole in my localhost.

Which are the main steps to configure ssh having vulnerabilities so low as possible?

Comment: Any particular reason to not put the crontab job on your host and pull the backups from the VPS?

Comment: So far, what have you researched and decided was not *secure enough*?  There are plenty of [options out there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) that aren't really Distro dependent, outside of the install process.